# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<String>

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters

I am getting this message:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to
>   List

It's in this part `for` loop that the error appears:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int nomeSorteado = gerador.nextInt(nomes.size() - 1);
    nomesSorteados[i] = nomes[nomeSorteado];
}
```

The part of `nomesSorteados[i] = nomes[nomeSorteado];` is the line with the error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't access elements of a `List` with the array index syntax, you need to call `list.get(index)` or `list.set(index, value)` or `list.add(value)` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `nomesSorteados` or `nomes` have type List. You can't index Lists with `[index]` subscript but you can call `get`/`add` methods on it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int nomeSorteado = gerador.nextInt(nomes.size() - 1);
    nomesSorteados.add(nomes.get(nomeSorteado));
}
```